# How to comment out an arbitrary range of lines using bash?

Tags: bash, sed

Say I have the following `file.txt`

```
some line 

{
  hey it's me, another line
}

# START FOO
These lines
need to be commented
out
# END FOO

Some other line
```

How could I comment out all lines between the markers `# START FOO` and `# END FOO` in `bash`? Is it possible to do it in a one-liner?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or ... it should get you started..

Comment: Since you have been around here for a long time, you should at least show what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sed '/START FOO/,/END FOO/s/^/#/' file.txt
```